# Returning remote object in rpyc

Tags: python, rpyc

I have a remote server like below which already has an initialized class and i have set protocol config as allow public attrs True.

```
import rpyc

class SharedClass(object):
    def __init__(self,string):
        print string

    def action(self):
        print 'i am doing something'

s=SharedClass('hi')

class MyService(rpyc.Service):
    def on_connect(self):
        pass

    def on_disconnect(self):
        pass

    def exposed_get_shared(self):
        return s

if __name__=='__main__:
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    t=ThreadedServer(MyService,port=18861,protocol_config={"allow_public_attrs":True})
    t.start()
```

At the client side if i try to connect directly it is working, whereas
when i try to make connection inside a function and return the object
i am getting an error

**Client**

**Direct connection**

```
>>>Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>>Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>conn=rpyc.connect('localhost',18861)
>>>share=getattr(conn.root,'get_shared')
>>>share
<bound method MyService.exposed_get_shared of <__main__.MyService
object at 0x011BA698>>
>>>share=getattr(conn.root,'get_shared')()
>>>share
<__main__.SharedClass object at 0x00B6ED30>
>>>share.action()
i am doing something
```

If i try to do it in a function i am getting an error ;(

```
>>>def returnObject(objName, host, port):
...    conn = rpyc.connect(host, port)
...    print conn
...    attr = getattr(conn.root, 'get_' + objName)()
...    print attr
...    return attr
>>>share=returnObject('shared','localhost',18861)
<rpyc.core.protocol.Connection 'conn2' object at 0x0108AAD0>
<__main__.SharedClass object at 0x00B6ED30>
>>>share
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 168,
in __repr__
   return syncreq(self, consts.HANDLE_REPR)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 69,
in syncreq
   return conn().sync_request(handler, oid, *args)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sync_request'
```

My purpose is to have an object initialized in server and to have many client access it. The initialized class is thread safe and so multiple clients can use it.

I realize that i am missing something while doing this.

--

Adhithya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I have no real experience with rpyc, from your example it seems the only real difference is when executing the returnObject function the 'conn' reference is not retained, so I am guessing the situation has to do with garbage collection of whatever is referenced by 'conn'. With a slight modification to the returnObject function so that 'conn' is returned and retained outside the function, the example seems to execute.

```
>>> import rpyc
>>> def returnObject(objName, host, port):
...     conn = rpyc.connect(host, port)
...     print conn
...     attr = getattr(conn.root, 'get_' + objName)()
...     print attr
...     return conn, attr
... 
>>> conn, share = returnObject('shared', 'localhost', 18861)
<rpyc.core.protocol.Connection 'conn1' object at 0x10b0676d0>
<__main__.SharedClass object at 0x1091ff790>
>>> share
<__main__.SharedClass object at 0x1091ff790>
>>> share.action()
```

As I am involved in development of another python remote-object solution [Versile Python](https://versile.com/products/vpy/), just for fun here is an alternative implementation using that solution (requires VPy dev release 0.7.2, next version will have some conflicting API changes). Remote service providing SharedClass access:

```
from versile.quick import *
from versile.vse.native.python import VPythonObject
VSEResolver.add_imports()

class SharedClass(object):
    def action(self):
        return u'I am doing something'

shared = SharedClass()

class Gateway(VExternal):
    @publish(show=True, ctx=False)
    def get_shared(self):
        return VPythonObject(shared)

service = VTPService(lambda: Gateway(), auth=None)
service.start()
```

Client code to access the service:

```
>>> from versile.quick import *
>>> VSEResolver.add_imports()
>>> gw = VUrl.resolve('vtp://localhost/')
>>> shared = gw.get_shared()
>>> shared._v_activate() # required for activating as remote-python proxy
>>> shared.action()
u'I am doing something'
>>> gw._v_link.shutdown()
```

Comment: If i return conn and attr, my code is working. Thanks for your help.